# A way for jq to output paths in a way itself can read?

Tags: path, jq

Is there a way to make `jq` output paths in a way itself can read?

Example input:

```
{
    "foo": [{
        "bar": 2,
        "bor": 3
    }]
}
```

Output the location and value of "bar" by e.g.:

```
jq -c 'tostream | select(.[0]|index("bar"))'
[["foo",0,"bar"],2]
```

Is there a way to instead output the path in the `jq` path selection format, i.e. `.foo[0].bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq **can** read paths specified as JSON arrays.  See in particular `getpath` and `setpath`.  `fromstream` also reads paths in the array format.

Answer (score 1):

There's no builtin way to do it as far as I know, but it shouldn't take much to roll out an implementation.

There's only three cases you would need to worry about: when the path is empty, the path contains a string, and the path contains a number.

If it's empty, it's just referring to the input itself.  If it's a string, it's a property of an object. If it's a number, it's an index into an array.

So you could use this:

```
def to_expression($path): $path |
    if length == 0
        then "."
        else map(
            if type == "string"
                then ".\"\(.)\""
            elif type == "number"
                then "[\(.)]"
            else
                error("unexpected path type: \(type)")
            end
        ) | add
    end;
```

Note that this always wraps the property names in quotes.  It's not strictly required, but easier than trying to figure out if it is actually needed.